PySpark Dataframe Transformation to MongoDB
I am using pyspark to transform some data for insertion into MongoDB.
My source object is:
[
{
        "salary": "8 - 15 million",
        "expiration": "31/05/2024",
...
}, 
...
]

And now i want to transform "salary" field from string to be stored in mongoDB as a object.
The expected result stored in mongoDB is:
salary: {
   type: 0,
   min: 8.0,
   max: 15.0,
   fixed_value: Null
}

I try to write code but it not work. The data insert to database is not object, it is string or array:
def parse_salary(salary):
    # My logic
    return {"type": 2, "min": None, "max": None, "fixed_value": None}
salary_schema = StructType([
    StructField("type", IntegerType()),
    StructField("min", FloatType()),
    StructField("max", FloatType()),
    StructField("fixed_value", FloatType())
])
parse_salary_udf = udf(parse_salary)
df = df.withColumn("salary", parse_salary_udf(df["salary"]))
...
rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict())
def insert_into_mongodb(partition):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/", username='admin', password='mypassword')
    db = client["mydb"]
    collection = db["jobs"]

    for record in partition:
        collection.insert_one(record)
rdd.foreachPartition(insert_into_mongodb)

Thank you so much  !
